# How can I reference more than one variable in an if condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a newbie and I'm doing the classic Tic Tac Toe exercise on Python,
I wanted to use more than one variable in an if, like this:

```py
if boarda[1],boarda[2],boarda[3]='X':
   print ('player X wins)
```

The output is Syntax error, is it possible to do this? and if it is how can I write it? Big thanks

I want to check against `and` and `or`, so the duplicate is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could always do the intuitive

```
if boarda[1] == 'X' or boarda[2] == 'X' or boarda[3] == 'X'
```

But a far better way to approach this is to use the `in` operator:

```
if 'X' in (boarda[1], boarda[2], boarda[3])
```

For a long list you'd probably want a list comprehension:

```
if 'X' in [boarda[x] for x in range(1, 4)]
```

For checking against `and`, it's even easier:

```
if boarda[1] == boarda[2] == boarda[3] == 'X'
```

For arbitrary types:

```
vals = (boarda[1], boarda[2], boarda[3])
if all(v == 'X' for v in vals)
```

Comment: The problem is I need it to be True when three of them are 'X' and those just function like an or(if one of them is true then true)
I could do if boarda[1] == 'X' and boarda[2] == 'X' and boarda[3] == 'X' but that'd be way too long for all the cases(8 possible winning cases) isn't there a shorter way? Thanks for replying so fast

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot, the fourth will do it for me, it's about the same length as what I was using, but the correct syntax of course